# Single product variation wrap padding, extra space woocomerce

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, padding, overlapping

can someone help me with adding some space in a single product subpage? The price is too close to Add to cart button (overlapping). I tried to use inspection tools, but have little knowlage of CSS.

[Link](https://www.petrasrawcakes.com.au/product/raw-mango-cream-pie/)

[Photo snipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uws79.jpg)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css rule:

```
.single_variation {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```